# Multiple parts of subURL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website which I would like to have a /info on the end of the user profile.

e.g

example.com/user/music

Is there any way to do this with .htaccess?

I'm using PHP $_GET queries to access certain parts

(example.com/profile.php?user= is example.com/user/)

Thanks, Phil

Edit: I mean example.com/PhilGibson/photos for instance. Preferably kept in .htaccess

Comment: If /user/ is already mapped to /profile.php?user= you likely already have an .htaccess file.  Can you post the relevant parts of that so that a more specific recommendation can be made?

Comment: Do you mean you want that when people access a page at `example.com/user/` they are actually accessing `example.com/profile.php?page=user`? I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Okay, what I mean is a way for two sub parts. I.e example.com/user/admin/pictures, like profile.php?user=admin?section=pictures